# sorting numerical values R

Tags: r

I have a table (out) that looks like this:

```
V1    V2    V3
A     x     0
A     y     1
A     z     10
A     a     11
A     b     12
...   ...   ...
A     c     2
A     d     21
A     e     22
...   ...   ...
A     f     3
```

I sorted this table based on V3 with this function

```
sorted.out <- out[order(out$V3), ]
```

However I want the values in V3 in numerical order like 1,2,3,4, ..., 10,11,12, ...
and not like it is now 1,10,11,12, ...

How can I do this?

When I use str(out) my V3 comes out as a factor variable. I should change it to numerical probably?

Comment: Ask yourself why it was turned to factor.  Usually on import the column (if numeric) will import as such.  Is there some non-numeric character in a cell causing the factor conversion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `sorted.out <- out[order(as.numeric(as.character(out$V3))), ]`

Note that you must first convert to `character`, then to `numeric`. Otherwise you may end up with the order according to the factors.